# Color Snapping When Using VertexColors with a Tube with BSplineCurve as an Argument

Tags: graphics3d, splines, system-limitations

I think I've identified a bug in how `VertexColors` are treated when rendering a `Tube` object where the underlying data is a `BSplineCurve` (it also affects `BezierCurve`), it appears that the colors of the tube are "snapping" to the nearest primitive colors for some reason. Here's a minimum working example that should produce an Orange `Tube` object, but the object is definitively Red in color:

```
Graphics3D[{Tube[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], 0.05,
VertexColors -> {Orange, Orange}]},
PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, Automatic},
Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Some testing has shown that which color is snapped to is very sensitive to the particular vertex colors chosen, for instance setting the `VertexColors` argument to `{Hue[0.166],Hue[0.167]}` renders a tube with one end green and one end red:

[image]

Get rid of the `BSplineCurve` within the `Tube` call and the object has the proper color:

[image]

This is in Mathematica 9 on Mac OS X 10.10.2, but I have verification that this behavior persists in the latest version of Mathematica 10 (10.0.2) for Windows (thanks Mr. Wizard!).

If this is indeed a bug, is there a work-around aside from abandoning `BSplineCurve`? It would be preferable for me to be able to render `Tube` objects smoothly.

Comment: I guess I'm not supposed to tag my own question as a bug, but this really does seem like a bug. Should I tag it as such?

Comment: I do not think this should be tagged as a bug yet; it hasn't had enough attention.  I added a tag that might generate more interest.  If that fails I'll add a bounty.  By the way the behavior persists in 10.1.0.

Comment: Confirmed with v9 and v10.1.0 (OSX 10.9.5)

Comment: This workaround works for me :`Graphics3D[{Orange, 
  Tube[BSplineCurve[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}}], 
   0.05]}, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, Automatic}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]` but it might be probably too basic for more complex plots ?

Comment: @SquareOne The issue is when you set the vertex colors, not when you set the color of the entire object as you do in your code. In the simple example I had provided both vertexes have the same color.